# Stop Header Name Change After Dividing in R

Tags: r

What do I need to change about my code so that when I create a new column after dividing one column **(using the column number to reference the column instead of the column name)** into another it does not rename the column header, e.g. if I take the below table:

```
Variable     Value   Total
Chicken      5       9
Fish         3       5
Beef         2       3
Chicken      4       9
Beef         1       3
Fish         2       5
```

And divide Value into Total to get a percentage **(again, using the column number, not name)**, it adds ".Value" to the end of the "Percent" column header (e.g. below):

```
Variable     Value   Total   Average.Value
Chicken      5       9       0.56
Fish         3       5       0.60
Beef         2       3       0.67
Chicken      4       9       0.44
Beef         1       3       0.33
Fish         2       5       0.40
```

What can I change about my code to prevent the auto-suffix and simply keep my column header "Average" instead of "Average.Value"? To further complicate things, if I attempt to simply rename the header with something like:

```
names(dd)[4] <- "Average"
```

it doesn't work! The reason I am not wanting to use the column name is my actual case is much more complex than the example here and I am looping through multiple columns within a column range.

Here is the sample code:

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,text="
Variable     Value
Chicken      5
Fish         3
Beef         2
Chicken      4
Beef         1
Fish         2")

dd$Total <- with(dd,ave(Value,Variable,FUN=sum))

dd$Average <- round(dd[2] / dd[3], 2)
```

Comment: @stevenjoe  Time to read some introduction to R, no?

Comment: @Pascal, happily! Any suggestions? I looked for books awhile ago on Amazon but could not find any.

Comment: @stevenjoe http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce OP's issue? I can't.  I get "Value" for the column name.

Comment: @RichardScriven I cannot.

Comment: @stevenjoe  Could you come back your question to clarify this, please?

Comment: When I run the "sample code" provided above, I get column header names of "Variable, Value, Total, Average.Value". I am just coping above code into RStudio and running it.

Comment: @Pascal, thanks for the info via the link BTW!!!

Comment: @stevenjoe you should be able to find hundreds of books on R on Amazon, but it is sometimes hard with a one letter language to not get lost in unrelated stuff.  The free ones on that link will probably get you started, but if you want a print book, I really like "R in Action".  It looks like there is an "R for Dummies" which is a pretty new edition, and "Learning R", but I haven't looked at either of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(dd[2])
# [1] "list"
typeof(dd[,2])
# [1] "integer"

#try this
dd$Average <- round(dd[,2] / dd[,3], 2)
```

Comment: Now I need the help.  Could someone explain the down-vote, please?

Comment: Nothing more than other (deleted) answer. Will reconsider my vote according to what happens in this thread.

Comment: @Pascal but wasn't this the first answer?

Comment: @Pascal Is there some way I might still see that deleted answer? I don't mean to be dense, but any clue about how to fix this and/or what to avoid in the future would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am neither the downvoter nor I would recommend a deletion of your post but it is usually a good idea to explain your code, why it answers the question what the OP's mistake was, etc.